# why is keycloak removing the SSL in the redirect uri?

Tags: redirect, ssl, amazon-web-services, https, keycloak

***We have a simple requirement where:*** 
**PS**: https:/ === https://

When user hits *https:/company_landing.company.com* , they should be redirected to keycloak login page (at *https:/ourcompany-keycloak.company.com*). User enters his/her keycloak login credentials. Upon successful login to keycloak , they will be presented to the company_landing page.

***The trouble is :***

When User types - **https:/company_landing.company.com**

Keycloak tries to bring up the landing page but gives 500 Internal server error and says "Incorrect redirect uri" and in the browser I see this:

https:/ourcompany-keycloak.company.com/auth/realms/realm1/tokens/login?client_id=company_dev&state=aaaafffff-559d-4312-a8be-123412341234&**redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcompany_landing.company.com%3A8081%2F%3Fauth_callback%3D1**

If you observe the redirect uri above, I think the problem is that instead of https the redirect uri starts with http and http:/company-landing.company.com doesn't exist.

***Settings:*** 
*keycloak settings:* -

*Realm --> settings --> login : Require SSL* = all Requests (tried with "external" also)

*Applications-->realm1-->settings-->Redirect URI* = https://company_landing.company.com/*

*AWS load balancer:* 
Port config: 443(https) forwarding to 8443

I am confused as to why it is stripping the SSL? The above works fine when testing on local environment(probably because its http://localhost) but this always gives an invalid redirect url when trying to access any link that is ssl encrypted.

-mm

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry forgot to update this. I think the problem was that the AWS loadbalancer settings were incorrect. I resolved this by choosing the following for Load balancer listener settings :  443 and https for loadbalancer port and protocol AND 80 and https for instance port and protocol.

Comment: Port 80 and HTTPS? ok, so you also installed the certificate on the instance behind the ELB?

Comment: Yes , we also initated the certificate on th instance behind the ELB

Comment: so you have got this working now? i'm having the same issue. im using nginx as loadbalancer/reverse proxy

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did anyone solve this issue? I'm not using SSL in the EC2 instance, and I dont want that overhead (load balancer and final instance).

Answer (score 8):

You have to add the following property in the proxy configuration json file, (by default proxy.json) as an application attribute (same level as "adapter-config"):

```
"proxy-address-forwarding" : true,
```

This configuration attribute is not documented, however present in the sources of the proxy configuration: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/proxy/proxy-server/src/main/java/org/keycloak/proxy/ProxyConfig.java

Comment: I'm using a helm chart for kubernetes where this is set and I still miss the 's' in 'https'. Is there a way of checking?

Comment: link is outdated

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a certificate to be installed or use changes in adapter config.

This needs to be done in your `standalone.xml`, `standalone-ha` or `domain.xml` (as the case may be) as documented in the Keycloak document reverse proxy section https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy

Assuming that your reverse proxy doesn’t use port 8443 for SSL you also need to configure what port HTTPS traffic is redirected to.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
    ...
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"
        proxy-address-forwarding="true" redirect-socket="proxy-https"/>
    ...
</subsystem>
```

Add the redirect-socket attribute to the http-listener element. The value should be proxy-https which points to a socket binding you also need to define.

Then add a new socket-binding element to the socket-binding-group element:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public"
    port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    ...
    <socket-binding name="proxy-https" port="443"/>
    ...
</socket-binding-group>
```

Comment: This way you offload https/ssl/tls handling to your load balancer/ reverse proxy  and still use https/ssl

Comment: `redirect-socket="proxy-https"` does the trick