# Keycloak Gitpod Flask OIDC: oauth2client.client.FlowExchangeError: Invalid response: 301

Tags: flask, keycloak, gitpod, flask-oidc

I'm trying to implement [`Flask-OIDC`](https://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [`Keycloak`](https://www.keycloak.org/) in a Flask app run inside a [`Gitpod`](http://gitpod.io/) workspace.

I'm running the application and the `Keycloak` server like this:

```
./keycloak-11.0.3/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0 &
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 &
```

*Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34410749/9098350)*

I'm able to redirect to the `Keycloak` login page for regular users from within the `Flask` application, but when I login with an existing user I get the following:

> oauth2client.client.FlowExchangeError: Invalid response: 301

---

My `client_secrets.json` currently looks something like this:

```
{
  "web": {
    "auth_uri": "http://keycloak-hostname-gitpod/auth/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    "issuer": "http://keycloak-hostname-gitpod/auth/realms/realm",
    "userinfo_uri": "http://keycloak-hostname-gitpod/auth/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
    "client_id": "client",
    "client_secret": "client_secret",
    "redirect_uris": ["http://flask-app-hostname-gitpod/oidc_callback"],
    "token_uri": "http://keycloak-hostname-gitpod/auth/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "token_introspection_uri": "http://keycloak-hostname-gitpod/auth/realms/realm/openid-connect/token/introspect"
  }
}
```

Relevant client configuration inside keycloak:

```
Root URL:            http://flask-app-hostname-gitpod/*
Valid Redirect URIs: http://flask-app-hostname-gitpod/*
Admin URL:           http://flask-app-hostname-gitpod/*
Web Origins:         http://flask-app-hostname-gitpod
```

I use `http` in all of these urls instead of `https`, because when I use `https` `Keycloak` says the `redirect_uri` is invalid. This seems to be the actual problem here since the gitpod urls use `https`, but I'm not sure how to handle this. I've tried some solutions like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084604/why-is-keycloak-removing-the-ssl-in-the-redirect-uri), but couldn't get them to work.

Relevant part routing:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    if oidc.user_loggedin:
        return (
            'Hello, %s, <a href="/private">See private</a> '
            '<a href="/logout">Log out</a>'
        ) % oidc.user_getfield("preferred_username")
    else:
        return 'Welcome anonymous, <a href="/private">Log in</a>'


@app.route("/private")
@oidc.require_login
def test():
    return "test"
```

Parts of `standalone.xml` that might be relevant:

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true" read-timeout="30000" proxy-address-forwarding="true" />
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true" read-timeout="30000" />
```

**Update**

After following changing the http urls to https as [Jan Garaj suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944314/keycloak-gitpod-flask-oidc-oauth2client-client-flowexchangeerror-invalid-respo#comment118345614_66944314) and setting the `OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI` I don't get the `invalid response: 301` error anymore:

```
OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI = "https://flask-app-hostname-gitpod/oidc_callback"
```

Now I'm able to go to the keycloak login form, but on logging in I now get:

> oauth2client.client.FlowExchangeError: Invalid response: 401.

These are the requests made:

```
https://keycloak-hostname-gitpod/auth/realms/realm/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=session_code&execution=execution&client_id=client&tab_id=tab_id
https://flask-app-hostname-gitpod/oidc_callback?state=state&session_state=session_state&code=code
```

Requests inside the network inspector:
[image: requests network]

Comment: Add/edit client configuration of valid redirect URI and add also https app url there to resolve `redirect_uri is invalid` problem. BTW: OIDC protocol requires https in real prod setup. You should to provide also more details. Apparently some endpoint returns 301, but it's not clear which endpoint has that problem.

Comment: @JanGaraj Thank you for your help. I've set everything to https now. When I did this the redirect_uri was still http and failed, but I was able to fix that by setting the `OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48864406/9098350). I've updated my question with some more detail. The redirect seems to work now, but the authentication seems to be failing.

Comment: Double check token url config and keycloak logs. App has a problem to exchange code for token - app may have a problem to reach token endpoint.

Comment: @JanGaraj Thank you so much for the insight, your comment helped me figure out what was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial end error I've finally figured out what the problem was.

The redirect problem in the original question was solved by setting `OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI`:

```
OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI = "https://flask-app-hostname-gitpod/oidc_callback"
```

The `oidc_callback` request was still not working however, I was getting this:

> oauth2client.client.FlowExchangeError: Invalid response: 401.

[Jan Garaj's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944314/keycloak-gitpod-flask-oidc-oauth2client-client-flowexchangeerror-invalid-respo#comment118369818_66944314) made me realise the problem was that the token endpoint request was not working.

I had checked the token endpoint uri multiple times and copied the value from:

```
https://flask-app-hostname-gitpod/auth/realms/demo/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

but it still didn't work.

The reason it didn't work was actually unrelated to my `Keycloak` configuration, but the way my keycloak server was running inside `Gitpod`.

`Gitpod` set the port that the keycloak server was running on to `private`. Because the keycloak server was running on a private port, the request to the follwing url failed:

```
https://keycloak-hostname-gitpod/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

After making the port public it worked.

[image: ports]

> if you already know that you want a particular port exposed, you can configure it in .gitpod.yml:

```
ports:
  - port: 5000
    onOpen: open-preview
  - port: 8080
```

https://www.gitpod.io/docs/config-ports